# What method is used to assign values to raster projected raster cells in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, projection-mathematics

I have a raster in GCS NAD83 with a resolution of 0.008333 (see properties below)

[image]

I want to project it to NAD83 /Conus Albers with a new pixel resolution of 2500m. Can I do this using the save as option as shown below? If so, what is the method of assigning new values to the new (larger) cells?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the user interface of Save Raster Layer as... does not have an option for selecting the resampling method.

However, you can use Raster-Projections-Warp either without changing the coordinate system for changing just the resolution, or by giving the source and target CRS for warping the image by the same. This tool gives you a drop down menu for selecting some alternative method for Nearest resampling.

[image]

Comment: For a complete answer did you know what resampling method the Save Raster Layer as... UI of QGIS use ? I gess it's nearest as it's the GDAL default but QGIS dev may have chosen something else so....

Comment: I thought also that it is nearest but I am not sure any more.